# How to solve/troubleshoot VScode SSH could not establish connection to remote "hostname"?

Tags: linux, bash, visual-studio-code, ssh, remote-access

I'm trying to connect via remote connection to a host with VScode SSH, but I keep getting "could not establish connection to 'hostname', Connection timed out".

I'm confused because it was working perfectly fine and then it stopped working out of the blue. I have changed the connection time limit from 15 to 25 but no use

I did not change the hostname or any config related to ssh in vscode

I can still connect to the host in PuTTY, but I'd like to use vscode

OUTPUT:

```
[18:07:41.551] Log Level: 2
[18:07:41.553] remote-ssh@0.80.0
[18:07:41.553] win32 x64
[18:07:41.558] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+sjc-xdm-035", attempt 1
[18:07:41.559] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false
[18:07:41.559] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[18:07:41.559] "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {"sjc-xdm-035":"linux"}
[18:07:41.559] "remote.SSH.path": undefined
[18:07:41.559] "remote.SSH.configFile": undefined
[18:07:41.559] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
[18:07:41.559] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
[18:07:41.560] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
[18:07:41.560] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": false
[18:07:41.560] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[18:07:41.560] "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": []
[18:07:41.560] "remote.SSH.loglevel": 2
[18:07:41.560] "remote.SSH.enableDynamicForwarding": true
[18:07:41.560] "remote.SSH.enableRemoteCommand": false
[18:07:41.560] "remote.SSH.serverPickPortsFromRange": {}
[18:07:41.560] "remote.SSH.serverInstallPath": {}
[18:07:41.570] SSH Resolver called for host: sjc-xdm-035
[18:07:41.570] Setting up SSH remote "sjc-xdm-035"
[18:07:41.585] Using commit id "c3511e6c69bb39013c4a4b7b9566ec1ca73fc4d5" and quality "stable" for server
[18:07:41.588] Install and start server if needed
[18:07:41.589] Checking ssh with "ssh -V"
[18:07:41.619] > OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 
[18:07:41.620] > 3.0.2

[18:07:41.622] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 50979 "sjc-xdm-035" bash
[18:07:41.626] Terminal shell path: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
[18:07:41.834] > ]0;C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
[18:07:41.835] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[18:08:02.946] > ssh: connect to host sjc-xdm-035 port 22: Connection timed out
[18:08:02.963] > The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
[18:08:04.220] "install" terminal command done
[18:08:04.220] Install terminal quit with output: ]0;C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exessh: connect to host sjc-xdm-035 port 22: Connection timed out
[18:08:04.220] Received install output: ]0;C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exessh: connect to host sjc-xdm-035 port 22: Connection timed out
[18:08:04.221] Resolver error: Error: The connection timed out
    at Function.Offline (c:\Users\vesiripu\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.80.0\out\extension.js:1:585840)
    at c:\Users\vesiripu\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.80.0\out\extension.js:1:583348
    at Object.t.handleInstallOutput (c:\Users\vesiripu\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.80.0\out\extension.js:1:583623)
    at Object.t.tryInstall (c:\Users\vesiripu\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.80.0\out\extension.js:1:681707)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async c:\Users\vesiripu\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.80.0\out\extension.js:1:644347
    at async Object.t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\vesiripu\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.80.0\out\extension.js:1:647692)
    at async Object.t.resolve (c:\Users\vesiripu\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.80.0\out\extension.js:1:645426)
    at async c:\Users\vesiripu\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.80.0\out\extension.js:1:722509
[18:08:04.226] ------




[18:08:44.271] Picking SSH host
[18:08:46.634] Selected sjc-xdm-035
[18:08:46.637] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -o ClearAllForwardings=true "sjc-xdm-035" bash
[18:08:46.641] Terminal shell path: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
[18:08:46.843] > ]0;C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
[18:09:08.006] > ssh: connect to host sjc-xdm-035 port 22: Connection timed out
```

Comment: `Resolver error: Error: The connection timed out`, your DNS configuration maybe?  Is there a DNS config in VSCode or does it use system configs?